# Concatenate float with string and round to 2 decimal places

Tags: c++, string, append, rounding, pass-by-reference

So I have a function below formatted as polymorphic void display(string& outStr). The output from this function should basically be formatted into one large string, which will be saved to the outStr parameter and returned to the calling function.

I have successfully formatted my large string into multiple lines but I would like to round my float value to 2 decimal places but I can't figure out how with the way I'm currently appending my strings. I tried using the round() and ceil() functions as some posts online have suggested, but 6 zeros still appear after each decimal place. I would appreciate some help with this as I've been looking for solutions for a while but none of them have worked.

Additionally, I was wondering if the to_string() function I used to convert my float to a string would compile and execute correctly in C++98? I'm using C++11 but my teacher is using C++98 and I'm extremely worried that it won't compile on her end.

If not, can anyone suggest how else I could achieve the same result of turning a float into a string while still formatting multiple lines into the outStr string parameter and returning it to the function? I am not allowed to change the function's parameters, it must stay as display(string& outStr)

My output is a lot longer and complex but I simplified the example for the sake of getting a short and easy solution.

Again, I would appreciate any help!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include "Math.h"

void Math::display(string& outStr){
    float numOne = 35;
    float numTwo = 33;
    
    string hello = "Hello, your percent is: \n";
    outStr.append(hello);
    string percent = "Percent: \n";
    outStr.append(percent);
    float numPercent = ceil(((numOne / numTwo) * 100) * 100.0) / 100.0;
    outStr.append(to_string(numPercent));
    outStr.append("\n");
        
}
```

Output should look like:

```
Hello, your percent is:
Number:
106.06%
```

Comment: You may be looking for `std::ostringstream`. As in `std::ostringstream os; os << "Percent: " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << numOne / numTwo * 100 << '%'; outStr = os.str();`

Comment: Is there a way to round the float to two decimal places in that statement?

Comment: That's what `std::setprecision(2)` does. Have you tried it? In what way does it fail to meet your requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to do any crazy conversions. Since the function is called display, my guess is that it's actually supposed to **display** the value instead of just save it to a string.

The following code demonstrates how that can be accomplished by just formatting your printing.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  double percentage = 83.1415926;
  std::cout << "Raw: " << percentage << "%\n";
  std::cout << "cout: " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << percentage << "%\n";
  printf("printf: %.2f\%%\n", percentage);  // double up % to print the actual symbol
}
```

Output is:

```
Raw: 83.1416%
cout: 83.14%
printf: 83.14%
```

If the function is as backwards as you describe it, there are two possibilities. You don't understand what's actually required and are giving us a bad explanation (my guess given that function signature), or the assignment itself is pure garbage. As much as SO likes to rag on professors, I find it difficult to believe that what you've described and written is what the professor wants. It makes no sense.

A couple notes: there is nothing polymorhpic about the code you've shown. `to_string()` exists as of C++11, which is easily seen by looking up the function ([Link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)). There is also a discrepancy between what your code attempts to print versus what your output is, and that's before we even get to the number formatting portion. "Percent" or "Number"?